# Reputation decreased but not shown in history

Tags: discussion, support

I'm pretty sure yesterday I had rep. 1,597. Today, I have 2 points less, 1,595. I wanted to make sure that I didn't mess up with some answer and see which one was it, so I went to my profile and clicked on the *reputation* tab, but there's not a `-2` event.

I'm not complaining about losing the reputation, I just wonder if this event (whatever it is) should be logged in the *reputation* tab as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reason for your loss of 2 points was the deletion of a "stub" that was left behind when a [question was migrated](https://superuser.com/questions/976203/how-to-get-6-000-dropbox-filelinks)(10K only link).  You had edited the question, which gave you two points, but the question has since been deleted which then lost you reputation for the edit.

Your reputation losses due to "cleanup" events are typically not shown to you because you lack the reputation to see deleted posts.  There are many questions on [StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178037/lost-reputation-due-to-removed-post) regarding this.

The criteria for the Community Roomba to clean up questions is [here](https://superuser.com/help/roomba)

Comment: Thanks, if this is due to lack of reputation to see deleted posts I guess it's ok, just a bit confusing if you don't know about it.

Comment: @nKn: You may see more of these, unrelated to migration.  I suspect the expansion of the Late Answer and LQ Post queues has led to review of many old questions and answers.  Over the last couple of weeks, I've seen a steady drip of rep reductions for edits and answers on old questions that have been removed.